# xmemory0 exception at void deallocate

Tags: c++, access-violation

My code builds and runs fine up until the actual end of the program when it has an issue with line 909 of xmemory0.

```
void deallocate(pointer _Ptr, size_type _Count)
        {   // deallocate object at _Ptr, ignore size
        _Mybase::deallocate(_Ptr, _Count);
        }
```

my code is the start of a very basic twitter client, the issue only really occurred when i started building my classes. I'm 99% sure its to do with my vector but i haven't really done anything with it yet so I'm not sure. When I search for this error online I cant find any similar issues. As I'm using the twitcurl library it would be really hard and unfair to ask anyone to build everything just to compile my code, but here it is just so you can see what I have
this is my header file with all my classes

```
#pragma once
#ifndef CLASSES_H
#define CLASSES_H
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include"rapidjson/document.h"
#include"rapidjson/reader.h"
#include"rapidjson/writer.h"
#include"rapidjson/stringbuffer.h"
#include "rapidjson/rapidjson.h"
#include"rapidjson/prettywriter.h"
using namespace rapidjson;


class tweet {
public:
    tweet();
    ~tweet();
    std::string userName;
    std::string userid;
    std::string tweetData;

};
class timeline {
public:
    std::vector<tweet> tweets;
    timeline();
    ~timeline();
    void set_userTimeline(std::string);
};
class user:public timeline {

    public:
        user();
        std::string name;
        std::string screenName;
        std::string user_ID;
        timeline userTimeline;
        void loadUserData(std::string);
        std::string get_name();
        std::string get_screenName();
        std::string get_user_ID();
        void set_name(std::string);
        void set_screenName(std::string);
        void set_user_ID(std::string);
        ~user();
};

#endif /*CLASSES_H*/
```

my implementation file

```
#include "classes.h"

tweet::tweet()
{

}
tweet::~tweet()
{

}

timeline::timeline()
{

}
timeline::~timeline()
{

}
void timeline::set_userTimeline(std::string)
{

}
user::user()
{

}
std::string user::get_name()
{
    return name;
}
std::string user::get_screenName()
{
    return screenName;
}
std::string user::get_user_ID()
{
    return user_ID;
}
void user::set_name(std::string n)
{
    name = n;
}
void user::set_screenName(std::string sn)
{
    screenName = sn;
}
void user::set_user_ID(std::string id)
{
    user_ID = id;
}

void user::loadUserData(std::string input)
{
    bool userLoaded = false;
    std::string json;
    json = input;
    Document d;
    d.Parse(json.c_str());
    assert(d.IsObject());
    assert(d.HasMember("id_str"));
    assert(d.HasMember("name"));
    assert(d.HasMember("screen_name"));
    assert(d["name"].IsString());
    assert(d["screen_name"].IsString());
    assert(d["id_str"].IsString());
    set_user_ID(d["id_str"].GetString());
    set_name(d["name"].GetString());
    set_screenName(d["screen_name"].GetString());


}
user::~user()
{

}
```

and my main

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include "twitcurl.h"
#include "curl/curl.h"
#include"classes.h"

FILE _iob[] = { *stdin, *stdout, *stderr };

extern "C" FILE * __cdecl __iob_func(void)
{
    return _iob;
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    ///first screen login or exit

    std::string choice;
    std::cout << "Press" << std::endl << "1 to login" << std::endl << "2 to exit" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> choice;
    int intChoice = std::stoi(choice, nullptr);
    if (intChoice == 0)
    {
        return 0;

    }
    else if (intChoice == 1)


    {
        /*choice = "";
        intChoice = 0;*/
        std::string userName = "Jordash90";
        std::string passWord = "*******";
        /*std::cout << "Please enter your twitter username->" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> userName;
        std::cout << "Please enter your twitter password->" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> passWord;*/

        twitCurl twitterObj;
        std::string tmpStr, tmpStr2;
        std::string replyMsg;
        char tmpBuf[1024];

        /* Set twitter username and password */
        twitterObj.setTwitterUsername(userName);
        twitterObj.setTwitterPassword(passWord);

        //SETMYKEYS AND SECRET OAUTHSTUFF
        twitterObj.getOAuth().setConsumerKey(std::string("bHnCXjV*************47Jk"));
        twitterObj.getOAuth().setConsumerSecret(std::string("fmjE*********VrzK7JoZWg28NECB0Eu5xsAQxXbOYdjjA"));

        //
        std::string oAuthUrl;
        twitterObj.oAuthRequestToken(oAuthUrl);
        twitterObj.oAuthHandlePIN(oAuthUrl);

        twitterObj.oAuthAccessToken();

        std::string myAccessTokenKey;
        std::string myAccessTokenSecret;
        twitterObj.getOAuth().getOAuthTokenKey(myAccessTokenKey);
        twitterObj.getOAuth().getOAuthTokenSecret(myAccessTokenSecret);
        //save these for later
        std::ofstream tokenKeySave;
        std::ofstream tokenSecretSave;
        tokenKeySave.open("twitterClient_token_key.txt");
        tokenSecretSave.open("twitterClient_token_secret.txt");

        tokenKeySave.clear();
        tokenSecretSave.clear();

        tokenKeySave << myAccessTokenKey.c_str();
        tokenSecretSave << myAccessTokenSecret.c_str();

        tokenKeySave.close();
        tokenSecretSave.close();

        /////actually trying to do something with this 

        user currentUser;
        /* Account credentials verification */
        if (twitterObj.accountVerifyCredGet())
        {
            twitterObj.getLastWebResponse(replyMsg);

            currentUser.loadUserData(replyMsg);


            std::cout << "User name: " << currentUser.get_name() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "User ID: " << currentUser.get_user_ID() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "User screen name: " << currentUser.get_screenName() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "login successful! :) " << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            twitterObj.getLastCurlError(replyMsg);
            printf("\ntwitterClient:: twitCurl::accountVerifyCredGet error:\n%s\n", replyMsg.c_str());
        }
    }

    system("PAUSE");


    return 0;

};
```

Comment: It means that you corrupted memory somewhere. Very suspicious is `FILE _iob[] = { *stdin, *stdout, *stderr };`. `FILE` objects are not copyable. Redefining the internal function `__iob_func` is also asking for trouble.

Comment: Is that the smallest possible form of your code that will reproduce the problem? What inputs do you use to repro the problem?

Comment: @RaymondChen The file _iob part is necessary to get the library im using working on visual studio 2015 as it is quite old and was initially used on vs06 or something. You wont be able to reprocuce the error unless you build libcurl and twitcurl which would take some time. what im wondering is if this error could be in any way related to the fact that my user class has an instance of timeline in it and that my timeline class is a vector of tweets? this only started happennig when i introduced the latter two classes to my code.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Sorry I answered your question above man.

Comment: So this is the absolute minimal amount of code to repro the problem? You can't even remove the `cout` lines after you've logged in? Or your `cin` for asking the user what they want to do?

Comment: @MatsPetersson are you okay mate?

Comment: Your replacement `_iob` does not have `_IOB_ENTRIES` elements, [which is what the documentation says its size is supposed to be](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798083.aspx).

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'm not looking for anyone to reproduce the errors. I think I've made rookie mistakes in my classes and I'm asking if I have. More specifically with the vector in my timeline class.

Comment: There are multiple problems with your `_iob` declaration. It is too small, which means that when `tokenKeySave.open` tries to open the file for saving, it will index off the end of the array and corrupt memory. Also, `*stdin` is a circular reference, because `stdin` is `#define`d to be `#define stdin (&__iob_func()[0])` which is a reference back to the `_iob` structure, so you are initializing `_iob` with itself.

Comment: @RaymondChen, FILE _iob[] = { *stdin, *stdout, *stderr };  is what my lecturer told the lab TA's to get us to do to use this library. Apologies if I seem quite slow on this. Does that just mean that I should have FILE_iob[20] instead?

Comment: Your lecturer gave you bad advice. I don't know what the correct answer is, but what your lecturer gave you is definitely wrong.

Comment: @RaymondChen That's cool man but thats not what is causing the problem anyway, I can step through my program and step into it at then very end and its when its calling my destructors and trying to delete that vector I think that it throws an access violation and stops at that void deallocate function.

Comment: Heap corruption is like that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to me not declaring the tweet class public to the timeline class.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. That would have resulted in a compile-time error, not a runtime error. Besides, in the code you posted, the `tweet` class is already fully public.

Comment: it still fixed it.

Comment: Then maybe I don't understand what you mean by "declaring the tweet class public to the timeline class". The tweet class and timeline class are siblings, so they are not public "to" each other. They are just public in an absolute sense. Please share the actual line of code that changed in order to fix the problem.

Comment: @RaymondChen class timeline: public tweet

Comment: Oh, you're not using standard terminology. That should be "deriving the timeline class from the tweet class." (Why does a timeline have a collection of tweets, and is also itself a tweet?) I don't see how that fixes the problem, seeing as there's nothing in timeline that uses the base class. Can you explain? Without an explanation, this answer will not be useful to others.

Comment: @RaymondChen Does it seem like i know why it worked man? If I was to guess I would say that it was because it needed access to the tweet class destructor... In what way is timeline a tweet? the homeTimeline is a collection of tweets is it not? I dont even use twitter mate.

Comment: I think what actually happened is that changing the size of the `timeline` class changed the way memory is laid out in the heap, which means that the memory corruption is now somewhere else.